# How to fill DATASET in tables from DATABASE C #

Tags: c#, sql

I have one database with three tables I want to copy them to one dataset, how to do it?

```
public DataSet SelectDset()
        {
            try
            {
                string str = "SELECT * FROM Information_Schema.Tables";
                ds = new DataSet();
                Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                da.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                Close();
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags for your questions! Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Could you show your code, please? then we can help you to solve the problem.

Comment: What is `Open();` opening?

Comment: public void Open()
        {
            con.Open();
        }

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this query 
**"SELECT * FROM Information_Schema.Tables"** will only retrieve the list of tables and views in the database but doesn't retrieve the records in the tables. To restrict it to retrieving base table types only, you would have to include a WHERE clause as shown below.

Secondly, to retrieve all the records in the tables, you would have to loop through the tables list and build the queries to retrieve the records(rows)

You may try this

```
    public DataSet SelectDset()
    {
        DataTable dtTablesNames=new DataTable();      
        try
        {
            Open();
            //get the list of tables in the database into a DataTable
            sTablesNamesQuery="SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' Order by TABLE_NAME";
            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sTablesNamesQuery, con);
            sda1.Fill(dtTablesNames);
            //               
            DataSet dsAllTables = new DataSet();
            StringBuilder sbQuery = "";
            //build the queries that will be used to retrieve the tables rows
            foreach (DataRow dr in dtTablesNames.Rows)
            {
                sbQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM " + dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()+";");                    
            }
            //
            SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sbQuery, con);
            sda2.Fill(dsAllTables);
            sda1.Dispose();
            sda2.Dispose();
            Close();
            return dsAllTables;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
   }
```